# Ubuntu 21.04 Goes Through Install, Then Exits With Error

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

Trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu from a USB drive booted with EFI (it did not give the option to boot otherwise) to a new SSD and it goes most of the way through the process, then fails with:

`install apt-cdrom add -m -d=/media/cdrom failed to finish in 10 seconds`

It goes on to say that there was no output from the command. Prior to that, it creates the partitions, unpacks the image, configures the locales, [several quick things to fast to note], creates initramfs, then gets to Contextual Process Job and gives the error. How does one get around that?

Comment: How did you flash the ISO to USB?  Did you verify the integrity of your download before flashing?  Does the flashed installation media pass integrity checks?  During installation are you connected to the internet and have you chosen to download updates while installing?

Comment: Installer mounts hybrid flash drive as /media/cdrom. You can try adding toram boot parameter if you have more than 4GB of RAM, so installer is totally in RAM. It still will have the mount. Or is a grub install not finding ESP - efi system partition (fat32 with boot,esp flags)? To add toram, edit the linux line like you do for nomodeset for nVidia driver. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: The partitions appear to be creating properly and the system is connected to the Internet. No option that I typically see on Ubuntu installations to download updates while installing: it boots to the desktop. Yes, I verified the integrity of the download and media.

Comment: I recreated the USB drive in a running version of Ubuntu which I did not have before (I used a Windows application before) and now it boots, then installs without errors. It now even asks if UEFI or non-UEFI is to be used which it did not do before. First time in the years of running Ubuntu that I was ever able to create a valid bit of media of any sort.